How to boot Luks encrypted Linux from second SSD (before optical drive) on MacBookPro 13 mid-2012
On MacBookPro, Mid-2012 13", A1278 details https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.5-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html
Main SSD(upgraded from HDD few years before) is OSX 10.15.7.
I have replaced Optical drive with 2TB SSD (https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Dual+Hard+Drive/13787).
I have installed TUXEDO-OS-3-202410081541.iso(https://os.tuxedocomputers.com/TUXEDO-OS-3-202410081541.iso) as Luks encrypted on 2 TB SSD.
My idea was that I will just use alt/option key on boot and I could chose: main ssd(OSX 10.15.7) or 2 TB SSD (Luks encrypted Linux)
But this is not working.
When I do alt/option key on boot I can chose: "MAIN" or "EFI Boot" and both end up in main SSD, OSX 10.15.7. This "EFI Boot" icon is of HDD, when I have installed Linux "EFI Boot" was icon of USB disk, so I am assuming that MacBookPro is recognizing that second 2 TB SDD is bootable, maybe problem is with Luks.
If it is possible, how can I achieve dual booting from both drives SSD drives, where second is Luks encrypted Linux ?
If only problem is Luks encrypted Linux I can live with just Linux, but I have not tested this in practice.

Have you asked on the Linux Stack? As the Mac seems to be working...

@SolarMike made some progress since yesterday, will update question, still have problem but this problem was related to UXEDO-OS-3-202410081541.iso because with kubuntu-22.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso I can come to GNU GRUB but not more. I do have feeling this is somehow related to macbookpro booting from disk0, where optical drive was originally.

I have made new question Problem with dual booting Linux from second SSD (where optical drive was ) on MacBookPro 13 mid-2012, with correct explanation of problem.
Problem described here was somehow related to TUXEDO-OS-3-202410081541.iso(https://os.tuxedocomputers.com/TUXEDO-OS-3-202410081541.iso)
